# Create a sql foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, t-sql

I wish to create a constraint that state as below

```
Code.CodeTable ( CodeID smallint, CategoryID smallint,....)  --> Parent Table
Admin.Document( DocumentTypeID smallint,.....)  --> Child Table
```

The FK will be Admin.Document.DocumentTypeID map with Code.CodeTable.CodeID

I wish to have the constraint that only check `Code.CodeTable.CodeID` which the `Code.CodeTable.CategoryID = 15` only.

Comment: You can't make a foreign key constraint across databases, or is that your naming convention--to put periods in the table name?  If that is your table naming convention, I don't recommend it.

Comment: @OMGPonies: the OP is referring to a schema with the period and not another database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As OMG Ponies already said - you cannot create fk constraints across databases, but if those are just odd table names with dots in them (highly discouraged! since SQL Server already uses a dotted schema: (database).(schema).(object name) and thus having dots in your table names is just asking for trouble at some point....), then you should be able to create your constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [Admin.Document]
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_AdminDocument_CodeTableCodeID
  FOREIGN KEY(DocumentTypeID) REFERENCES [Code.CodeTable](CodeID)
```

Since you have dots in your table names, you need to enclose those names in square brackets [].

Basically, you need to modify the child table and tell SQL Server which column in that child table refers to what parent table and column in the parent table.